# Error while emitting RecordedSimulation in Gatling Tool

Tags: java, gatling

Getting below error when I am trying to run `gatling.sh` file. From my understanding getting compilation issue in RecorderSimulation.scala file while doing `gatling.sh`. Please see the below Error and help me

```
JAVA = "java"                                                                                                                                                               
11:51:37.496 [ERROR] i.g.c.ZincCompiler$ - Error while emitting 
RecordedSimulation                                                                                          
Method too large: RecordedSimulation.<init> ()V                                                                                                                             
11:51:37.520 [ERROR] i.g.c.ZincCompiler$ - one error found                                                                                                                  
11:51:37.531 [ERROR] i.g.c.ZincCompiler$ - Compilation crashed                                                                                                              
sbt.internal.inc.CompileFailed: null                                                                                                                                                    
at sbt.internal.inc.AnalyzingCompiler.compile(AnalyzingCompiler.scala:122)                                                                                                  
at sbt.internal.inc.AnalyzingCompiler.compile(AnalyzingCompiler.scala:95)                                                                                                   
at sbt.internal.inc.MixedAnalyzingCompiler.$anonfun$compile$4(MixedAnalyzingCompiler.scala:91)                                                                              
at scala.runtime.java8.JFunction0$mcV$sp.apply(JFunction0$mcV$sp.java:23)                                                                                                   
at sbt.internal.inc.MixedAnalyzingCompiler.timed(MixedAnalyzingCompiler.scala:186)                                                                                          
at sbt.internal.inc.MixedAnalyzingCompiler.$anonfun$compile$3(MixedAnalyzingCompiler.scala:82)                                                                              
at sbt.internal.inc.MixedAnalyzingCompiler.$anonfun$compile$3$adapted(MixedAnalyzingCompiler.scala:77)                                                                      
at sbt.internal.inc.JarUtils$.withPreviousJar(JarUtils.scala:215)                                                                                                           
at sbt.internal.inc.MixedAnalyzingCompiler.compileScala$1(MixedAnalyzingCompiler.scala:77)                                                                                  
at sbt.internal.inc.MixedAnalyzingCompiler.compile(MixedAnalyzingCompiler.scala:146)                                                                                        
at sbt.internal.inc.IncrementalCompilerImpl.$anonfun$compileInternal$1(IncrementalCompilerImpl.scala:343)                                                                   
at sbt.internal.inc.IncrementalCompilerImpl.$anonfun$compileInternal$1$adapted(IncrementalCompilerImpl.scala:343)                                                           
at sbt.internal.inc.Incremental$.doCompile(Incremental.scala:120)                                                                                                           
at sbt.internal.inc.Incremental$.$anonfun$compile$4(Incremental.scala:100)                                                                                                  
at sbt.internal.inc.IncrementalCommon.recompileClasses(IncrementalCommon.scala:180)                                                                                         
at sbt.internal.inc.IncrementalCommon.cycle(IncrementalCommon.scala:98)                                                                                                     
at sbt.internal.inc.Incremental$.$anonfun$compile$3(Incremental.scala:102)                                                                                                  
at sbt.internal.inc.Incremental$.manageClassfiles(Incremental.scala:155)                                                                                                    
at sbt.internal.inc.Incremental$.compile(Incremental.scala:92)                                                                                                              
at sbt.internal.inc.IncrementalCompile$.apply(Compile.scala:75)                                                                                                           
at sbt.internal.inc.IncrementalCompilerImpl.compileInternal(IncrementalCompilerImpl.scala:348)                                                                              
at sbt.internal.inc.IncrementalCompilerImpl.$anonfun$compileIncrementally$1(IncrementalCompilerImpl.scala:301)                                                              
at sbt.internal.inc.IncrementalCompilerImpl.handleCompilationError(IncrementalCompilerImpl.scala:168)                                                                       
at sbt.internal.inc.IncrementalCompilerImpl.compileIncrementally(IncrementalCompilerImpl.scala:248)                                                                         
at sbt.internal.inc.IncrementalCompilerImpl.compile(IncrementalCompilerImpl.scala:74)                                                                                       at io.gatling.compiler.ZincCompiler$.doCompile(ZincCompiler.scala:211)                                                                                                      
at io.gatling.compiler.ZincCompiler$.delayedEndpoint$io$gatling$compiler$ZincCompiler$1(ZincCompiler.scala:216)                                                             
at io.gatling.compiler.ZincCompiler$delayedInit$body.apply(ZincCompiler.scala:39)                                                                                           
at scala.Function0.apply$mcV$sp(Function0.scala:39)                                                                                                                         
at scala.Function0.apply$mcV$sp$(Function0.scala:39)
at scala.runtime.AbstractFunction0.apply$mcV$sp(AbstractFunction0.scala:17)                                                                                                 
at scala.App.$anonfun$main$1$adapted(App.scala:80)                                                                                                                          
at scala.collection.immutable.List.foreach(List.scala:392)                                                                                                                  
at scala.App.main(App.scala:80)                                                                                                                                             
at scala.App.main$(App.scala:78)                                                                                                                                            
at io.gatling.compiler.ZincCompiler$.main(ZincCompiler.scala:39)                                                                                                            
at io.gatling.compiler.ZincCompiler.main(ZincCompiler.scala)                                                                                                        
Choose a simulation number:                                                                                                                                                
[0] computerdatabase.BasicSimulation                                                                                                                                        
[1] computerdatabase.advanced.AdvancedSimulationStep01                                                                                                                      
[2] computerdatabase.advanced.AdvancedSimulationStep02                                                                                                                      
[3] computerdatabase.advanced.AdvancedSimulationStep03                                                                                                                      
[4] computerdatabase.advanced.AdvancedSimulationStep04
```

**Please suggest solution**

Comment: If you show the code, may be we will see what could cause the problem.

Answer (score 1):

This error is due to the size of the scala file being too large. You need to keep number of requests in a method to under 100. I faced the same issue and resolved it by splitting the script into two methods.

Answer (score 0):

You've managed to generate some piece of code that's too large with regard to the Scala language spec.

Please make sure you're using latest Gatling version (3.3.1 as of now) and upgrade if not.
If problem still happens, please reach out on [Gatling community mailing list](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/gatling) and provide your code.

Comment: I am using same latest version of gatling. 
And My previous issue got resolved (My Method of class was containing more that 1200 request because of that Gatling has thrown  Method too large exception. As per my analysis i modified RecorderSimulation method and kept 200 requests only. After giving 200 request only it was running as excepted).

But I want to keep more request in gatling then how it will possible. Any suggestion.